# sprintf not correctly creating a valid file path

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run the following code, however I am getting an error when trying to read the text file

```
DATAopts.imgsetpath = 'C:\Users\z5085693\Downloads\matconvnet-calvin-master\matconvnet-calvin-master\data\Datasets\VOC2010\VOCdevkit\VOC2010\ImageSets\Main\%s.txt';
trainName = 'train';

trainIms = textread(sprintf(DATAopts.imgsetpath, trainName), '%s');
```

This yields the error:

> Error using textread (line 165)
>   File not found.

When I execute just the `sprintf` portion

```
sprintf(DATAopts.imgsetpath, trainName)
```

I simply get `'C:'` which is where the "File not found" error is coming from because obviously that's not the full path.

What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I have added the screen shot of the MATLAB widow. Its a MATLAB code.. why do you think its not a valid code?
I was following the `sprintf` example and in that example the variables are string so I was converting in that.

Comment: What is the error that you get? The code you posted had `(char type)` in it which wasn't valid but now I see that was your annotation

Comment: `Error using textread (line 165)
File not found.`
if I just execute `sprintf(DATAopts.imgsetpath, trainName)` the output is `C:`

Answer (score 2):

The character `'\'` is an escape character therefore you'll want to escape each of these backslashes prior to calling `sprintf` to get an *actual* backslash in the result.

```
escaped_imgsetpath = strrep(DATAopts.imgsetpath, '\', '\\');
result = textread(sprintf(escaped_imgsetpath, trainName));
```